# Is there a Widget / Views / Controls Explorer in Xamarin iOS Storyboard Designer?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Using Xamarin iOS designer (working with storyboard) in Visual Studio 2017 and finding it buggy. At times, I cannot even see views (controls) that definitely exist within the viewcontroller's view. Sometimes they reappear after changing the viewas (from iphone 5 to iphone 6, for example, and back). Sometimes you just can't select something like the UIStackView because it's subviews have filled all the internal space.
I am wondering if there is a control/views explorer like in xcode, so I could use that to select the controls instead of the design surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press CTRL + W, U  when you have the storyboard open and this will open up 'Document Outline' this will show you your controls and uiviewcontrollers etc. It's invaluable.

[image: Example]

You can also find it under the tab 'View' -> 'Other Windows' -> 'Document Outline'